# Zoom for graph in D3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, zooming, force-layout

I have javascript code that draws a graph using data stored in json file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
// style here
</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<div id="animviz"></div>
<script>
    var vv = window,
    w = vv.innerWidth,
    h = vv.innerHeight;

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, w])
    .range([0, w]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, h])
        .range([h, 0]);

    var svg = d3.select("#animviz")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h)
            .append("g")

    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    var force = d3.layout.force()
            .charge(-200)
            .linkDistance(50)
            .size([w, h]);

    d3.json("post000.json", function(error, graph) {
        force
                .nodes(graph.nodes)
                .links(graph.links)
                .start();

        var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
                .data(graph.links)
                .enter().append("line")
                .attr("class", "link")

        var myMouseoverFunction = function() {
            var circle = d3.select(this);
            circle.transition().duration(100)
                    .attr("r", 20 )
            node.append("title")
                .text(function(d) { return d.name});
        }

        var myMouseoutFunction = function() {
            var circle = d3.select(this);
            circle.transition().duration(500)
                    .attr("r", 10 );
        }
        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                .data(graph.nodes)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("r", 10)
                .attr("transform", transform)
                .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
                .call(force.drag)
                .on("mouseover", myMouseoverFunction)
                .on("mouseout", myMouseoutFunction);

        force.on("tick", function() {
            link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

            node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
        });

    });
</script>

</body>
```

However I can't zoom in or out this graph in a browser. I planned to use [similar example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680957) from documentation; however, in my case I load data from post000.json using d3.json that is asynchronous and I'm not sure how I can access this data when it's loaded to pass it as input to zoom function.

How can I draw a graph that I can zoom in with data stored in json?

Comment: Just set up the zoom in the callback.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on that?

Comment: If you start from the example, you could take its entire code and put that in your callback handler.

Comment: I can't because I also define variables outside callback.

Comment: You could move those variables into the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that works for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
// style here
</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<div id="animviz"></div>
<script>

    d3.json("post000.json", function(error, graph) {

        var vv = window,
            w = vv.innerWidth,
            h = vv.innerHeight;

        var svg = d3.select("#animviz")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h)
                .append("g")
                .call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0, 8]).on("zoom", zoom))
                .append("g");

        var color = d3.scale.category10();

        var force = d3.layout.force()
                .charge(-200)
                .linkDistance(50)
                .size([w, h]);

        force
                .nodes(graph.nodes)
                .links(graph.links)
                .start();

        var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
                .data(graph.links)
                .enter().append("line")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d + ")"; });

        function zoom() {
          svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
        }

        var myMouseoverFunction = function() {
            var circle = d3.select(this);
            circle.transition().duration(100)
                    .attr("r", 20 )
            node.append("title")
                .text(function(d) { return d.name});
        }

        var myMouseoutFunction = function() {
            var circle = d3.select(this);
            circle.transition().duration(500)
                    .attr("r", 10 );
        }
        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                .data(graph.nodes)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("r", 10)
                .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
                .call(force.drag)
                .on("mouseover", myMouseoverFunction)
                .on("mouseout", myMouseoutFunction);


        force.on("tick", function() {
            link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

            node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
        });

    });


</script>

</body>
```